# How can I swap tokens by using Ethereum private network?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, metamask, nft

For Main Network I can see **Buy, Send, and Swap** options active.
[image]

Whereas for private network, only the **Send** button is active other two options Buy, swap is disabled.
[image]

How can I perform that swap or buy option on Ethereum private network?

Comment: This question lacks details, like how the network is created and what particular buttons this authon is talking about.

Comment: @Mikko Ohtamaa , Thanks for the reply :)

In MetaMask wallet for Ethereum main net, I can see three options Buy, Send, Swap but for my Private Network It's showing only 1 option "Send"

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it doesn't seem to be about programming, but about buying/selling Ethereum.

Answer (score 0):

You can't swap or buy on Ethereum private network.
You can see the active swap button on default metamask local:8545 network.
But, for ex, when you swap eth to dai on local network, the metamask send eths to the metamask's swap router contract address, which is deployed on mainnet but that address does not exist on private network.